# derivative $\nabla \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^k}$ in the context of Geometric Calculus

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, geometric-algebras

Suppose $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{x - x'}$ is the position vector in $\mathbf{R^n}$, and $r = |\mathbf{r}| = |\mathbf{x - x'}|$.   Do we have $\nabla \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^k} = \frac{n-k-1}{r^k}$ or $\nabla \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^k} = \frac{n-k}{r^k}$? The former is from page 7 in [Tutorial on Geometric Calculus](http://geocalc.clas.asu.edu/pdf/Tutorial%20on%20Geometric%20Calculus.pdf)  by David Hestenes.  If this is not a typo, it is intriguing that $\nabla \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^k}$ is not equal to the $\nabla \cdot \frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^k}$ in ordinary vector calculus.

Comment: $\frac{n-k-1}{r^k}$ is a number where as $\nabla \frac{\textbf{r}}{r^k}$ is a vector, so it can't be right. How do you define $\nabla \textbf{r}$ ? like $\left(\nabla r_i\right)_{i=1}^n$ where $\textbf{r}=(r_1,...,r_n)$?

Comment: @idm $\nabla \frac{\textbf{r}}{r^k}$ is not a vector. It's the gradient of a vector, which is rank-2 tensor.

Comment: $r$ is the position vector, not $x$?  If so, why did you write $r = x-x'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without breaking into coordinates, we can just directly evaluate the derivatives using the chain rule:

$$\nabla \frac{r}{|r|^k} = \frac{\nabla \cdot r}{|r|^k} + (\nabla [r^2]^{-k/2}) r$$

The first term is, of course, just $n/|r|^k$.  The choice of writing things in terms of $r^2$ is for simplicity.

$$\nabla [r^2]^{-k/2} = -\frac{k}{2} [r^2]^{-k/2-1} (2r) = -kr |r|^{-k-2}$$

We can directly evaluate the result to get

$$\nabla \frac{r}{|r|^k} = \frac{n}{|r|^k} - \frac{k r^2}{|r|^{k+2}} = \frac{n-k}{|r|^k}$$

The result is just a scalar; there are no bivector terms.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if $\mathbf{r}$ is a vector, then on the right you have a divergence, not a gradient (let's find it in a Cartesian coordinates).

$$
\nabla\cdot\frac{\mathbf{r}}{r^k} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_i}\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_i^2}^k} = \frac{n-k}{r^k}
$$

Let's find the $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_i}$ of $\frac{x_i}{r^k}$:

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x_i}\frac{x_i}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_i^2}^k} = -\frac{k x_i^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_i^2}^{k+2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_i^2}^k}
$$

Multiplying and simplifying yield the following:

$$
\frac{(1-k)x_i^2 + \sum\limits_{j \ne i}x_j^2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_i^2}^{k+2}}
$$

Summing in the divergence will yield $n$ instead of $i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2$ on the top, which will cancel with bottom one and will get the original result $\blacksquare$.